# regex pattern starts with string and ends with whitespace

Tags: regex, scala

I'm trying to get one part of string from long line.
The original line is looks like

`val j = "(...), nickname=sally,25,student, from="Spain", (...)"`

and I want to get `nickname=sally,25,student` this one only.

I think regex pattern should be
`pattern= "nickname=([a-zA-Z0-9,])*(.+)\s$`
but it doesn't work like the way I want.

Is there any good suggestion?

Comment: Try this one: nickname=[\w,]+(?=,)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
pattern= "nickname\=([^\s])*"
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason the pattern `nickname=([a-zA-Z0-9,])*(.+)\s$` does not get the right match is because:

- nickname is not captured in the group, and there is more than that match only
- repeating the whole capturing group like this `([a-zA-Z0-9,])*` will capture only the value of the last iteration, being a `,` in this example.
- The `\s$` matches a whitespace char and then asserts the end of the string

You have to repeat the character class itself one or more times `[a-zA-Z0-9,]+` if there should be a nickname part (including the comma at the end)

With those changes, that pattern would look like:

```
\b(nickname=[a-zA-Z0-9,]+)(.+)\s$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DQYHWK/1)

---

If you don't need the second capturing group and want to get the match only:

```
\bnickname=[a-zA-Z0-9,]+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mx4E90/1)

Or without the comma at the end:

```
\bnickname=[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:,[a-zA-Z0-9]+)+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/scW51t/1)

For example, with a whitespace char at the end of the string:

```
val regex: Regex = """\bnickname=[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:,[a-zA-Z0-9]+)+""".r
val j = """(...), nickname=sally,25,student, from="Spain", (...) """
regex.findFirstIn(j).foreach(println)
```

Output

```
nickname=sally,25,student
```